# Standardize heuristic values

Tags: game-theory

I'm currently writing a [reversi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversi) AI. What it does is, it looks a few moves ahead and then evaluates the boards and gives them scores, depending on how good it is. I use a few methods for evaluating these scores.

For example, I have the formulas:

```
StoneScore = My Stones Amount - Opponent Stones Amount
PossibleMoveScore = My Possible Moves - Your possible moves
TotalScore = StoneScore + PossibleMoveScore
```

*There are a lot more actually, but I've just created this as example.*

However, as the game progresses, these functions are not really scaling. I mean if I'm getting a lot more stones then my opponent the `StoneScore`can be like `40` and the `PossibleMoveScore` can be just like 10.

In this case the `StoneScore` is a very big contributer to the `TotalScore`. Is there a way I can make them equally important.

I know that the range of `StoneScore` is between 0 and 64. And the range of the `PossibleMoveScore` is (a rough guess, I have no idea acutally) between 0 and `2*Opponent Stones Amount`

Is there a technique I can use to control these variables?

Comment: `StoneScore` can be positive or negative.

Comment: Absolutely, thanks :)

Comment: PossibleMoveScore is at most 64-9. But in practice is always less than this because to have 9 of your pieces, means you have 8-9 of your opponents. So, a safe bet is 64-18 as a max PossibleMoveScore that [probably] cannot be reached.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that a variable $x$ lies in the range $x_\min$ to $x_\max$ you can normalise it to be between 0 and 1 via the transformation:

$$x_{\mathrm{rescaled}} = \frac{x - x_\min}{x_\max - x_\min}$$

and your total score will always be between 0 and 2.

More generally you can apply any monotonic function $f(\cdot)$ that satisfies $f(x_\min)=0$ and $f(x_\max)=1$.